# Verification: if $\lim_{x \to a} f$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g$ do not exist, then $\lim_{x \to a} fg$ does not exist.

Tags: real-analysis

Intuition: $\infty \cdot \infty = \infty$

Formal Proof:
If $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f$ and $\lim \limits_{x \to a} g$ do not exist, then for any $\delta, n,m$ there are $x_1, x_2 \in \delta$ and $\epsilon_1, \epsilon_2$ such that

$\begin{equation}
|f(x_1) - n| > \epsilon_1
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
|g(x_2) - m| > \epsilon_2
\end{equation}$

**Let $x_1 = x_2$ (on this point alone I am doubtful... but the rest of the proof seems so reasonable that I'll continue)**

Suppose $\epsilon_1 > \epsilon_2$. Then

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
|f(x_1) - n| - |g(x_1) - m| &> \epsilon_1 - \epsilon_2 > 0 \\
|f(x_1) - n| - |-g(x_1) + m| &> \epsilon ' \\
|(f + g)(x_1) - (n+m)| &> \epsilon '
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

A similar case holds if $\epsilon_2 > \epsilon_1$

Edit: I realize the fallacy of this proof is in the fact that I am 'proving' non-existence of $f + g$ not $fg$....and even that if invalid because of the inference "let $x_1 = x_2$".

Comment: "Does not exist" is not the same as "$\infty$".

Comment: The result is not true: Take $f(x)=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if $x$ is rational}\\0&\text{ if $x$ is irrational}\end{cases}$ and $g=1-f$. Then the limits $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ and $\lim_{x\to a}g(x)$ never exist, but $fg=0$.

Comment: You also seem confused to the formalization of the phrase "the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist". The phrase "the limit $\lim{x\to a}f(x)$ exists" means that "there exists $L$ such that for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$". Its negation is "for all $L$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta>0$ there exists $x$ with $0<|x-a|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-L|>\epsilon$".

Comment: @LuizCordeiro well that clears things up

Comment: @LuizCordeiro In regards to the second comment, where is my confusion apparent?

Comment: @user_hello1 The order of the quantified variables ($n,m,\epsilon,...$) is wrong. $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$ should depend only on $n$ and $m$, and not on $\delta$.

Comment: @user_hello1 The logic is wrong. As you nicely pointed out, you cannot assume that $x_1=x_2$. You're going from an statement of the form "There exist $x_1$ and $x_2$ such that..." to "$x_1=x_2$", which is not a valid inference rule. Also, you did not prove that "the limit of $f+g$ at $a$ does not exist". To prove it, you should arrive to this phrase at some point, which you never did.

Comment: @user_hello1 I strongly recommend you take some time and talk to your instructor about how the underlying logic of proofs should be used, what is a proof, etc... Actually, it's a good idea to show him this "proof", so he can help you figure out what's not right.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition is wrong. The fact that the limit does not exist it does not means that it's infinity. Let's define a function $f(x)=1$ if $x\in\mathbb Q$ and $-1$ otherwise. Then for any $a\in\mathbb R$, the limit $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ does not exist. Now choose $g(x)=2f(x)$. Then $f(x)g(x)=2$ for any $x\in \mathbb R$, so the limit exists and is always $2$.

Comment: I thought $\lim \limits_{x \to a} fg$ meant $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(g(x))$ not $\lim \limits_{x \to a} f(x) \times g(x)$

Comment: @gmoshkin You can guess that it's a product from two things in the question. First, both limits are at the same value $a$. If there is a limit at $a$ for $g$, no one guarantees that the limit is $a$, so the information about limit of $f$ at $a$ is useless. The second hint, in the "intuition", the question mentions a product $\infty\cdot\infty$

Comment: @gmoshkin $f(g(x))$ may not even be defined